# Firebase set value rewriting the children- Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am using Firebase real time database to save data in the below structure.

```
root
|----email
       |---A
       |---B
       |---C
```

Everything fine till here u when i am trying to add a child to the `email` with setValue() all the existing children are being overwritten.

**Expected structure:**

```
root
|----email
       |---A
       |---B
       |---C
       |---D
           |---D1
           |---D2
           |---D3
```

**Actual data structure being saved in firebase**

```
root
|----email
       |---D
           |---D1
           |---D2
           |---D3
```

I also tried `push().setValue()` but it is creating an unique key which is not required in my case and the data structure should be as above.

**My code:**

```
DatabaseReference root=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference;
DatabaseReference dEmail=root.child("email");
DatabaseReference dTrack=dEmail.child("D");
Map<String, Object> transportStatus = new HashMap<>();
transportStatus.put("D1", "A");
transportStatus.put("D2", "B");
transportStatus.put("D3", "C");
transportStatus.put("D4", "D");
dTrack.setValue(transportStatus);
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to suggest to use updateChildren,

```
    DatabaseReference root=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference;
   DatabaseReference dEmail=root.child("email");
   DatabaseReference dTrack=dEmail.child("D");
   Map<String, Object> transportStatus = new HashMap<>();
   transportStatus.put("D1", "A");
   transportStatus.put("D2", "B");
   transportStatus.put("D3", "C");
   transportStatus.put("D4", "D");      
  dTrack.updateChildren(transportStatus);
```

Comment: Working. Thanks a lot.